# how reference file published with build action content

Tags: c#, path, directory, resources, nuget

I have a c# project that needs to load some yaml resources to work, I have set them  with "build action":"content" and "copy to Output directory":"Copy if newer"

To load them I use simply a relative path, and everything works inside the project.

I realized xunit project that loads the library and everything still works fine.

Now I released the library on nuget and I am trying to reference on an Asp.Net Core, but when I try to load my files, the application tries to find them in the wrong folder:

The files are searched in relative path from the root asp.net project, but files are in C:\Users\[name]\.nuget\packages\[pakage name]\[version]\content

So I am wondering how can I get the "content" folder of the assembly in C#?

**UPDATE: I TRY TO EXPLAIN BETTER**

I have a visual studio solution, we call it `foo.sln` and a C# project that we call `foo.csproj`

The project is a netstandard 2.0 library and it's built to be consumed by other applications: cli, asp.net, core, wpf, etc...

The library is built to be multiplatform, so could run on Windows, Mac and on Linux

Inside the root of foo project there is a folder we call it `YamlDefinitions`
Inside of that folder we have a lot of .yaml files that needs to be loaded and parsed by my foo library.

So `foo.csproj` has something like:

```
<Content Include="YamlDefinitions\Definition1.yaml">
    <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
</Content>
<Content Include="YamlDefinitions\Definition2.yaml">
    <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
</Content>
<Content Include="YamlDefinitions\Definition3.yaml">
    <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
</Content>
<Content Include="YamlDefinitions\Definition4.yaml">
    <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
</Content>
```

These files are immutable, so I load them as content instead as resource

Now inside the c# code of my foo library, I have:

```
var filePaths = Directory.GetFiles("YamlDefinitions", "*.yaml", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly)

foreach (var filePath in filePaths)
{
     using (var reader = new StreamReader(filePath))
     {
          // Load the stream
          var yamlStream = new YamlStream();
          yamlStream.Load(reader);
          yaml = yamlStream.Documents.FirstOrDefault();
     }
}
```

That code search, loads and parse all yaml files that can find in the specified folder.

Everything seems ok, so now to test I create an xunit prject inside the `foo.sln`, we call it `footest.csproj`

Now I reference `foo.csproj` inside `footest.csproj`

```
<ProjectReference Include="..\Foo\foo.csproj" />
```

All tests passed so I pack the library and publish the nuget package: `foo.nuget`

Now I want try to use my nuget package, so I create a new console application with Net Core 2.2, we call it `MyConsoleApp.csproj`

I install my nuget package `foo.nuget`:

```
 <PackageReference Include="Foo" Version="1.0.0"/>
```

the package is installed and all yaml files are placed in

```
C:\Users\UserName\\.nuget\packages\Foo\1.0.0\content\YamlDefinitions
```

and in

```
C:\Users\UserName\\.nuget\packages\Foo\1.0.0\contentFiles\any\netstandard2.0\YamlDefinitions
```

The files are also visible inside  `MyConsoleApp.csproj` as linked files, but they are not physically present in the project.

Now I launch my `MyConsoleApp.exe,` and I get an error, because it's unable to find these yaml files, because the application tries to load them in the same path as `MyConsoleApp.exe`

Workaround: from visual studio I select all yaml files that are linked inside `MyConsoleApp.csproj` and I set as CopyIfNewer

Now inside cproj visual studio adds these lines of codes:

```
<Content Include="C:\Users\User\.nuget\packages\Foo\1.0.0\contentFiles\any\netstandard2.0\YamlDefinitions\Definition1.yaml">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </Content>
```

I run again `MyConsoleApp.exe` and everything works.

This workaround is bad because the end user should be able to use the nuget library without specifying manually to copy files.
If I release a new version of my library that contains new definitions, the end user should not be aware that these must be included in the project.

Anyway, there is a bigger problem:

I create a new ASP.NET Core 2.2 MVC Application, we call it `MyWebApp.csproj`

I install `Foo.nuget` and I try to use it.

I set manually to copy all Yaml definitions in output folder, and when I build they are automatically copied in `MyWebApp\bin\Release\netcoreapp2.2\YamlDefinitions`

I launch the web app and I get again an error, because my foo libray tried to find files in `MyWebApp\YamlDefinitions`, but files are in bin folder, so nothing works.

How can I fix my library and and publish as nuget in a way that all consumer applications can use it?

Comment: Have a look at [Including content files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/nuget/reference/nuspec#using-the-files-element-for-content-files)

Comment: @H.G.Sandhagen sorry I can't understand, my file are packed correctly in nuget, yes they are not copied in bin directory, but I don't care where they are, I just need a way to reference them.
I would like to avoid to specify an output directory for each of them in nuspec, they are really a lot of file.

I need a C# function that returns me: "C:\Users\[name].nuget\packages[pakage name][version]\content"

Comment: I am afraid that will not work becuse nuget packages are downloaded at build tile. When you install the application on a target system, they will not be there.

Comment: @H.G. Sandhagen sorry but I continue to do not understand. The files are used by nuget library, not by target application.
I need the library to be able to read the file that it needs. When you download the nuget package you download also the content files, just they are not in same directory as assembly dll, so I cant use relative path.
If I can't use relative path, because nuget place the file where it wants, I need a C# function to retrieve them.

Comment: Maybe I did not understand right. Correct me if I am wrong. You created a library which needs some config files to run. The library expects the files in the output folder (folder of the executable). Then you create a nuget package from this library and reference this package in a ASP.NET Core application. Then the nuget package is responsible to copy all things from the package to the folder tree of the referencing application. I did not do it before, but I know there is a way to do this.

Comment: @H.G. Sandhagen yes, you got right, the library needs those files and actually expect them in the output folder. But if they are in another place is not a problem, I just need the correct path to load them.

Comment: The files are immutable, no there is no need to copy them in any application, maybe is better to keep just a copy in the nuget folder.

Answer (score 0):

I can't find a C# function that retrieves the nuget folder where content files are stored and I doubt that could exist, but I found this working approach:

In `foo.csproj` file you need to specify that each file should be copied in output folder, this can be done with:

```
<Content Include="YamlDefinitions\Definition1.yaml">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      <PackageCopyToOutput>true</PackageCopyToOutput>
</Content>
```

You need to add `PackageCopyToOutput` to make working with nuget, unfortunately, this can't be done from visual studio UI and you have to edit `.csproj` manually.

In C# you have to use an absolute path because relative path is not the same in all kind of application (in a .NET cli is different from ASP.NET)

So you have to use a code like this:

```
var directory = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "YamlDefinitions");
var filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(directory, "*.yaml", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly)
```

Where `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory` return the output directory where content files are copied